# Delete Folders recently moved to a different directory after 10 days of moving

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

There is a directory where I am moving folders, from a different directory without any logic(randomly anytime) and these folders needs to be deleted after 10 days of their moving here.

So, will this work? -

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-10)
$path = "C:\Some\Path"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force
```

What I don't know is that this creation time parameter would be updated when I move it to the new directory???

Comment: If you don't have to keep folder names absolutely intact, an easy and robust solution is to prefix the folder name with a sortable date (i.e. formatted like `yyyyMMdd`) when you move.

Comment: okay, Alexander, if I can even rename it like your suggestion, even then this code needs to be run? right? so in that case how would u giv a solution of deletion after 10 days? can i ask?

Comment: hey matt,
Its not working in my testing environment, and actualy i need to deploy it on a  diff sytem, cant say it wl run thr or not?
is there any replacement to CreationTime parameter - like MovedTime or something?

Comment: are u sure abt this bcoz if u try moving a file from one location to another, this is not updating its modified date ....
pls check!

Comment: You can force an update to the modified time using `(gci file).LastWriteTime = Get-Date`

Answer (score 1):

As requested in comments, a solution with renaming folders:

Moving a folder:

```
$sOldPath = "C:\oldpath\foldertomove" # Change to your actual path
$sNewPath = "C:\newpath" # Change to your actual new path
$sDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyMMdd"

$oFolderToMove = Get-Item -Path $sOldPath
Move-Item -Path $sOldPath -Destination $sNewPath
Rename-Item -Path (Join-Path -Path $sNewPath -ChildPath $oFolderToMove.Name) `
    -NewName ("{0}-{1}" -f $sDate, $oFolderToMove.Name)
```

Resulting path: `C:\newpath\yyyyMMdd-foldertomove`

---

Deleting old folders:

```
$sNewPath = "C:\newpath" # Change to your actual new path
$sDateLimit = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-10)).ToString("yyyyMMdd")

# Assuming that all folders in $sNewPath have date-prefixed names.
Get-ChildItem -Path $sNewPath | 
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } |
    Foreach-Object {
        $sDate = [UInt32]($_.Name.Substring(0,8))
        if ($sDate -lt $sDateLimit) {
            # Deletes folder and everything in it. Remove -WhatIf switch to execute. 
            Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force -WhatIf 
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, ur 1st script is fully functional

The 2nd script is posing this error:

Remove-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's `$_.FullName`, not `$_.FullPath`. Fixed.